# How to make two divs overlap while being response in react with boostrap

Tags: html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, overlapping

So, I'm using React with Bootstrap v4. Currently, I'm working on making two div's overlap while still being responsive. I can get the div's to look the way I want in a larger viewport, but when sizing to a mobile view they become unresponsive and staggered messing up with the rest of the page.

[image]

CSS

```
  .max-width-1080 {
      max-width: 1080px;
  }

  .stack-top {
      left: -3rem;
      top: 5rem;
      border: solid 1rem black;
      background: black;
      border-radius: 1rem;
      color: white
  }

  .stack-bottom {
      right: -3rem;

      img {
          border: solid 1rem black;
          background: black;
          border-radius: 1.5rem;
      }
  }

  img {
      object-fit: cover;
  }

  .img-1 {
      width: 500px;
      height: 678px;
  }
```

JSX

```
import React from "react";
import PDF from "./pdf";
import ".assets/styles/section1.scss";

const sectionOne= () => {
  return (
    <section className="section1">
      <div className="container-fluid text-center pt-5 pb-5 max-width-1080">
        <div className="row pb-5">
          <div className="col-md-6 stack-bottom">
            <img
              src="assets/images/1.jpg"
              className="img-1"
              alt="picture"
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6 stack-top">
            <PDF />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-12 text-center pt-5 pb-5 pdf-download">
          <a
            href="./1.pdf"
            download="1.pdf"
          >
            <button>
              <span>Download </span>
            </button>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default sectionOne;
```

What I'm looking for is a way to keep the image I posted above the same reguardless of the viewport width.